# How can we show that it is an integer 5-adic number?

Tags: number-theory, power-series, p-adic-number-theory

Show that the number $\frac{3}{8}$ is an integer $5$-adic and calculate the first five positions of its power series in $\mathbb{Q}_5$.

Could you explain me how we can conclude that $\frac{3}{8}$ is an integer $5$-adic number?

Also, is there a methodology to find the power series of a rational number in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: What kind of examples of rational numbers as $p$-adics have you seen? We have
$$\frac38-1=-\frac58,$$
which is divisible by five. Therefore the first digit is $1$.

Comment: I haven't seen any similar examples, that's why I am confused..
$$$$
What is the general method to show that a rational number is an integer $5$-adic?

Comment: If its denominator is not divisible by $5$ then it is a $5$-adic integer.

Comment: Is there a theorem which we could use, in order to show this?

Comment: It is a very basic fact that every integer that is not divisible by five is a unit in the 5-adic integers.

Comment: So do we have to check seperately the numerator and the denominator, to see if they are divisible by $5$?

Comment: Yes. Numerator needs to be divisible by a higher or equal power of five than the denominator. Then the 5-adic absolute value of the fraction is $\le1$. Equivalently, if you first cancel all the fives that you can, then no fives should remain as factors of the denominator.

Comment: So, you mean that if we have a rational number $\frac{m}{n}$, then it must be: $\displaystyle{w_p(n)=0 \text{ and } w_p(m) \geq 0}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The (exponential) valuation is usually extended to rationals (or $\Bbb{Q}_p$) by the recipe
$$\nu_p(\frac mn)=\nu_p(m)-\nu_p(n).$$
Then $m/n$ is a $p$-adic integer, iff $\nu_p(m/n)\ge0$.

Comment: A ok.. Is there a theorem about it?

Comment: I would be very surprised if the result is not mentioned in your book. Not sure whether it would be promoted to a *Theorem*.

Answer (score 3):

By the sum formula of converging geometric series
$$
-\frac18=\frac{3}{1-5^2}=3\cdot1+3\cdot5^2+3\cdot5^4+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 3\cdot5^{2k}.
$$
This series is clearly an element of $\Bbb{Z}_5$, so we have
shown that $-8$ is a unit of $\Bbb{Z}_5$. We can get everything you need out of this:

- $-3$ is a 5-adic integer, $-1/8$ is a 5-adic integer. The 5-adic integers form a ring $\implies (-3)\cdot(-1/8)=3/8$ is a 5-adic integer.
- Using the above series expansion of $-1/8$ and the fact that $3/8=1+5\cdot(-1/8)$ we get that
  $$
  \frac38=1+3\cdot5+0\cdot5^2+3\cdot5^3+0\cdot5^4+\cdots.
  $$

Let's check the beginning by elementary means. The sums of the initial segment of that series are $1,16,16,391,391,\ldots$. We verify this by observing that
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac38-1&&=-\frac58&&\text{is divisible by $5$}\\
&\frac38-16&&=-\frac{125}8&&\text{is divisible by $5^3=125$}\\
&\frac38-391&&=-\frac{3125}8&&\text{is divisible by $5^5=3125$}
\end{aligned}
$$
and so forth.

---

A general method for finding a 5-adic series for a rational number is roughly the following. I first show how to represent $-1/m$ as a series, when $\gcd(m,5)=1$.
We can view $5$ as an element of $(\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z})^*$. It is of a finite order, say $a$. This means that $5^a\equiv1\pmod m$, or that $5^a-1=km$ for some integer $k, 0<k<5^a$. Then
$$
-\frac1m=-\frac k{km}=\frac{k}{1-5^a}=k\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty 5^{ai}\right).
$$
Here $k=\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}k_i5^i$ for some integers $k_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Putting these together gives us the series with a periodic sequence of coefficients. The length of the period is $a$, and digits are the $k_i$s. The minus sign is a bit of a nuisance. The way to negate such a series is to subtract it from
$$
0=5+4\cdot5+4\cdot5^2+4\cdot 5^3+\cdots.
$$
So for example with $m=7$ we see that $5^6-1=15624=7\cdot2232$. Here
$$2232=2\cdot5^0+1\cdot5+4\cdot5^2+2\cdot5^3+3\cdot5^4,$$ so we get a series with
a period of length six
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\frac17&=\frac{2232}{1-5^6}=
(2\cdot5^0+1\cdot5+4\cdot5^2+2\cdot5^3+3\cdot5^4+0\cdot5^5)\sum_{i=0}^\infty5^{6i}\\
&=\cdots\overline{032412}032412032412.
\end{aligned}
$$
The negated number is thus
$$
\frac17=\cdots\overline{412032}412032412033.
$$
If the denominator is divisible by a power of five, we simply shift the series an appropriate number of positions. So for example
$$
\frac1{35}=\cdots\overline{241203}241203241203.3.
$$
Above the numerator was $\pm1$. A larger numerator poses no problem, because we simply multiply the series.

Comment: This is admittedly a bit overkill for the purposes of calculating the first five $5$-adic digits.

Comment: What is the general method to show that a rational number is an integer $5$-adic?

Comment: If the denominator $m$ is not divisible by $5$, then we can view $5$ as an element of the multiplicative group $(\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z})^*$. Clearly $5$ has finite order $a$ meaning that $5^a\equiv1\pmod m$. So $5^a-1=km$ for some integer $k$. Then we can do as above
$$-\frac1m=\frac{k}{1-5^a}=k\sum_{n=0}^\infty 5^{an}.$$

Comment: Is there also an other way to calculate $\frac{3}{8} \pmod 5$ ?

Comment: Yes. Modulo five $8=3$, so $3/8=3/3=1$.

Comment: Is there an other way to find the first five positions of the power series in $\mathbb{Q}_5$ of $\frac{3}{8}$ ?

Comment: @evinda: You can reverse engineer the "check" calculation in the last paragraph. $3/8-1$ is divisible by five, so the first digit is $a_0=1$. Next we look for $a_1\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ such that $3/8-1-a_1\cdot5$ would be divisible by $25$. By solving the relevant congruence (or by trial and error) we see that $3/8-1-3\cdot5$ is divisible not only by $25$ but also $125$. This gives us $a_1=3$ and $a_2=0$. And so forth. You see a period $03$ repeating.

Comment: I prefer the completely simple-minded method I showed you in my answer to your other question, about $1/2$. It’s good for finding the quotient of any two $p$-adic numbers, not just integers.